# Sonar Scanner failed to analyze the code because of missing folder, how to ignore it?

Tags: java, sonarqube, devops, sonar-runner

I have created a project.properties file as follows and performing Sonar Analysis using `sonar-scanner`.

When I first wrote this properties file, `module1` contained both `src` and `gensrc` folders and the static code analysis was successful.

But the next time when performed the analysis, the `gensrc` folder was missing inside `module1`, so the analysis failed.

I want to know, how can I ignore the folders that are not present inside a module while running the `sonar-scanner`, even if it is mentioned in the `project.properties` file?

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=Project1
sonar.projectName=Project1
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.login=username
sonar.password=encryption

sonar.scm.disabled=true
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.modules= module1, module2


module1.sonar.projectBaseDir=/apps/bin/Project1
module1.sonar.sources=module1/src, module1/gensrc
module1.sonar.tests=module1/testsrc

module2.sonar.projectBaseDir=/apps/bin/Project1
module2.sonar.sources=module2/src
module2.sonar.tests=module2/testsrc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably override file properties by using command line parameters for specific projects. Usually, sonar scanner reads everything from a properties file and execute accordingly. If you want different properties for one or two projects and you don't want to change properties file then the best way is to pass command line arguments.

Hope it helps.